# How to get enum from string by using NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, enums

I have an enum AccountType.

Currently, in my Account class I have second thing:

```
public class Account
{
    public virtual long AccountId { get; set; }

    public virtual int AccountTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual AccountType AccountType
    {
        get
        {
            return (AccountType)AccountTypeId;
        }

        set
        {
            AccountTypeId = (int)value;
        }
    }
}
```

and in my *.hbm.xml I have

```
<class name="Account" table="tAccount">
    <id name="Id">
      <column name="AccountId" sql-type="bigint"/>
      <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="AccountTypeId" column="AccountType"/>
</class>
```

Works fine BUT, now I need to change column AccountType from int to string, and as a result, old code wouldn't work any more.

So, basically, instead of int, I need to take string from database and get enum from it.

How it's supposed to be done?

P.S Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: With [Enum.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already suggested by @Reniuz by using [`Enum.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.parse(v=vs.110).aspx) or better [`Enum.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783499(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public virtual AccountType? AccountType
{
    get
    {
        AccountType type;
        if (Enum.TryParse(AccountTypeString, out type))
            return type
        return null;
    }
    set
    {
        AccountTypeString = String.IsNullOrWhitespace(value) ? null : value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Depending on how often this is called you possibly should somehow "cache" the parsed value.
**UPDATE:** I changed it to a nullable as per request.

Comment: Nice one but, I have one more question. Ponetnially, I can have null value in AccountType column. And it this case I need to ignore the whole Account class, not just set its type to default. How can it be done?

Comment: @OlegsJasjko: See my update. Now it is a nullable and via `obj.AccountType.HasValue` you can check if it is set.

Comment: Em... so, now if AccountType column has null value, Account class will be ignored? Because so far its looks like only AccountType ignoring.

Comment: As I do not know you program I can't tell you the exact solution, but as in my previous comment: Via `obj.AccountType.HasValue` (where `obj` is an instance of `Account`) you can check if it is empty and ignore it if so.

Comment: The setter didn't work for me since `value` is not a string, so I did the equivalent of `AccountTypeString = value?.ToString()` instead.